# Need to understand terraform resource structure

Tags: terraform

I am reading terraform and found below code:

```
resource "aws_vpc" "vpc_main" {
  cidr_block       = "10.0.0.0/16"

  tags {
    Name = "Main VPC"
  }
}
```

Here I could not understand what **vpc_main** stands for in the resource definition. Could somebody explain?

Comment: It's a user-assigned name for the resource.

Comment: why do we need this name? can we create a resource without any name ?

Answer (score 2):

It's a user-defined name for the resource - without this you wouldn't be able to distinguish multiple instances of the same resource type.

See [the docs](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/resources.html) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Variable types and names in other programming languages are a good analogy. For example, in Java, you can declare a variable as follows:

```
String foo
```

The *type* of the variable is `String` and the *name* of the variable is `foo`. You must specify a name so you can (a) distinguish it from other variables of the same type and (b) refer to it later.

In Terraform, it's essentially the same idea:

```
resource "aws_instance" "foo" { ... }
```

Here, the *type* of the resource is `aws_instance` and the *name* is `foo`. You must specify a name so you can (a) distinguish it from other resources of the same type and (b) refer to it later. For example, to output the public IP address of that Instance, you could do the following:

```
output "public_ip" {
  value = "${aws_instance.foo.public_ip}"
}
```